# PS/2 to USB adapter doesn't work with Model M keyboard

Tags: keyboard, ps2-keyboard, usb-keyboard

I bought a server about 3 months ago from a friend, and I have only had time to tinker with it in the last week. I noticed that this server doesn't have any PS/2 ports, which meant configuring it was near impossible. I don't have any USB keyboards in the house, I only have an IBM Model M keyboard (built 1994) and another IBM keyboard that was built circa 2001. Both of them have PS/2 connections.

I bought an adapter off eBay, and when I used it with the Model M keyboard the three lights on the keyboard flashed for a split second, but then the keyboard is then unresponsive. I can bash away at the keys for ages and nothing will happen. The same applies to the later built IBM keyboard.

What could I do to make the adapter work? I am getting the loan of a USB keyboard in two weeks time, but I'd like a more permanent solution without having to rely on getting the loan of a keyboard every time I have to perform maintenance on the server. And as I already have two keyboards which work fine and I like using, I don't really want to have to buy another keyboard just for use on the server.

Comment: I don't understand your logic.  So you purchase an adapter instead of buying a cheap usb keyboard?

Comment: The money isn't the issue, it's the space. I don't have much space, and I'm already crammed in. I have two keyboards already, and to have a third that would be used maybe once every few months seems a waste to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PS/2 and USB connectors are not equivalent. *Many* devices can be used in both using a passive adapter (but then almost always USB->PS/2, not the other way around), but not all [[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_connector#Legacy_port_status_and_USB)].

There are "active adapters" available that connect to USB and simply gives you two PS/2 connectors. If this is what you have, then something is weird, but you probably have a pure rewiring adapter.

Comment: I did see those "active adapters", but I thought that these did the same job as what I bought (which is just a single adapter). Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Purchasing a USB keyboard would probably work out cheaper, quicker and easier than playing with different adaptors. [here](http://www.maplin.co.uk/ps-2-to-usb-active-adaptor-26315) is an active adaptor.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will shop around and if a keyboard is cheaper then I will have to bite the bullet. I have seen those adapters for a cheaper price but will look around more.

Answer (score 0):

IBM Model M keyboards require more power than that is provided by most USB<->PS/2 adapters. If you search the Net, you'll find one with ease.